# How to plot relative frequencies in R or Stata

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, stata

I have this dataset :

```
> head(xc)
  wheeze3 SmokingGroup_Kai TG2000 TG2012 PA_Score asthma3 tres3 age3    bmi     bmi3
1       0                1      2      2        2       0     0   47 20.861 21.88708
2       0                5      2      3        3       0     0   57 20.449 23.05175
3       0                1      2      3        2       0     0   45 25.728 26.06168
4       0                2      1      1        3       0     0   48 22.039 23.50780
5       1                4      2      2        1       0     1   61 25.391 25.63692
6       0                4      2      2        2       0     0   54 21.633 23.66144
  education3 group_change
1          2            0
2          2            3
3          3            3
4          3            0
5          1            0
6          2            0
```

Here
 `asthma3` is a variable that takes values 0,1 ;
 `group_change` takes values 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 ;
 `age3`  represents the age.

I would like to plot the percentage of people with `asthma3==1` as a function of the variable `age3`.
I would like 6 lines on the same plot obtained dividing the samples by `group_change`.

I think that this should be possible using `ggplot2`.

Comment: Are you treating `age3` as continuous and, if so, across what range? Do you have sufficient data to be able to do that for each level of `group_change`?

Comment: I should have enough data

Comment: For future questions, please show attempted code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a ggplot2 approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Create fake data
set.seed(10)
xc=data.frame(age3=sample(40:50, 500, replace=TRUE),
           asthma3=sample(0:1,500, replace=TRUE), 
           group_change=sample(0:6, 500, replace=TRUE)) 

# Summarize asthma percent by group_change and age3 (using dplyr)
xc1 = xc %.%
  group_by(group_change, age3) %.%
  summarize(asthma.pct=mean(asthma3)*100)

# Plot using ggplot2
ggplot(xc1, aes(x=age3, y=asthma.pct, colour=as.factor(group_change))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=40:50) +
  xlab("Age") + ylab("Asthma Percent") +
  scale_colour_discrete(name="Group Change")
```

Here's another ggplot2 approach that works directly with the original data frame and calculates the percentages on the fly. I've also formatted the y-axis in percent format.

```
library(scales) # Need this for "percent_format()"
ggplot(xc, aes(x=age3, y=asthma3, colour=as.factor(group_change))) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom='line') +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom='point') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=40:50) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format()) +
  xlab("Age") + ylab("Asthma Percent") +
  scale_colour_discrete(name="Group Change")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using Stata. The example data has three groups.

The proportions are computed taking the mean of `asthma3` which you identify as a binary variable.

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

set obs 500
set seed 135

gen age3 = floor((50-40+1)*runiform() + 40)
gen asthma3 = round(runiform())
egen group_change = seq(), to(3)

*----- pretty list -----

order age3 group_change 
sort age3 group_change asthma3
list, sepby(age3)

*----- compute proportions -----

collapse (mean) asthma3, by(age3 group_change)
list

*----- syntax for graph and graph -----

levelsof(group_change), local(gc)

local i = 1
foreach g of local gc {
    local call `call' || connected asthma3 age3 if group_change == `g', sort
    local leg `leg' label(`i++' "Group`g'") // syntax for legend
}

twoway `call' legend(`leg') /// graph
    title("Proportion with asthma by group")
```

This coincides with one of my first questions in [Statalist](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-07/msg00245.html). In Nick's words, you "build up the syntax" using a local macro and then feed that to `twoway`.

@NickCox, in a comment, suggests an alternative:

```
<snip>

*----- compute proportions -----

collapse (mean) asthma3, by(age3 group_change)
list

*----- graph -----

separate asthma3, by(group_change) veryshortlabel

twoway connected asthma31-asthma33 age3, sort ///
    title("Proportion with asthma by group")

<snip>
```

This second alternative creates new variables from the original `asthma3` which I abbreviate in the call to `twoway connected` as `asthma31-asthma33`.

Both alternatives produce a legend identifying groups. Labels I leave to you (see `help graph`).

Comment: this is working well but in the legend I obtain all the color with the same name (mean) asthma3. How can I change it in order to view the group number?

Comment: After the `collapse` you could also use `separate asthma3, by(group_change) veryshortlabel` and then you have a set of variables to plot against `age3'. With this syntax different colours are automatic.

Comment: Sorry this is not very clear to me. can you edit the stata sintax? I am very new to stata. I would like an output such as the one obtained using the eipi10 answer

Comment: It's not a good idea to assume that Stata users can understand/execute R code (or vice versa). If you want to show how the graph looks, you can simply introduce an image (or link) to your post. I've edited my answer to workout the issue with the legend.